# Hibernate 5 Lazy Loading Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I have a class of User that has a list (collection) of Projects:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_owner_id")
private Collection<Project> project = new ArrayList<>();
```

And at some point, I want to see the list of projects and I fetch them:

```
Session sessionF = sessionFactory.openSession();
sessionF.beginTransaction();        
user = sessionF.get(User.class, user.getId());
sessionF.getTransaction().commit();
List<Project> projects = (List<Project>) user.getProject();     
sessionF.close();
```

If I don't do something with `projects` it throws the error: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy – no Session`

But if I am adding a `int projectCount = projects.size();` it works just fine. Why does that happen and how can I resolve it without playing with `projects` here?

P.S. After I am closing the session I am just passing it through the `HttpServletRequest` and then going with a for loop over it in a `jsp` file.

Comment: In the first case, the lazy association is never loaded while the session is opened, but you try to load it after the session is closed, so there is no way to get the data out of the database anymore, hence the exception. In the second case, you load the lazy collection while the session is still opened, so it's still there in memoruy once it's closed.

Comment: Shouldn't the `user.getProject()` load it to the `List<Project> projects`? This is the part where I am confused. Why do the `projects.size()` load it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Fetching Strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/performance.html) section of Hibernate Reference Documentation

> Lazy collection fetching - a collection is fetched when the application invokes an operation upon that collection. (This is the default for collections.)

Returning your collection from an entity and assigning it to a variable does not involve calling a method on that collection.